# WordPress Uploads directory (CHMOD operation not permitted)

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, ftp, chmod

I moved my WordPress website to another domain by same hosting provider.
At the previous webhosting the upload folder seemed to work with 755 CHMOD setup on uploads directory - all subdirectories were set to 755.

Now I'm facing a weird issue because the system threw an error that this folder is not writable under 755 setup.

So I changed the CHMOD setup of uploads dir to 777, uploaded the file and reverted back to 755. Weird thing is that the subdirs 2013/month are set automaticaly to 777 now and I can't change them.

I tried using recursion in FileZilla, but the response was

550 CHMOD 755 10: Operation not permitted

any suggestions how to resolve this?

thank you in advance for your posts.

Comment: Try `chmod ($file, 0755);` as an example if you're running this from a script. With the added `0` - am not WordPress savvy.

Comment: I think in your old hosting company, your upload process was in the same group with your uploading directory. And in your new one, is not

Comment: server returns this warning: Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../uploads/2013/10) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/httpd/vhosts/...

Comment: @fred: wordpress is written in php.... chmod() is a core php function

Comment: @MarcB My mistake. However maybe the OP could write a function to test it and see if that will work instead(?)

Answer (score 0):

I would contact your host and have them check the ownership and group of your folders/files. You may not have permission to change them yourself, which would explain the issues you're having in FileZilla.